# Solve $|\{x : x \subseteq \{1,2,...,n\} \wedge \{1,4\} \subseteq X \wedge \{1,5\} \nsubseteq X\}|$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Solve $|\{x : x \subseteq \{1,2,...,n\} \wedge \{1,4\} \subseteq X \wedge \{1,5\} \nsubseteq X\}|$.

I defined all the above as |A| because it is easier to follow.

I got that |A| = |{1,4}| = 1 , is that true? I added a picture.

[image]

Comment: $|\{1,4\}|$ is $2$, but perhaps you mean $A=\{\{1,4\}\}$ instead? In that case, how about $\{1,3,4\}$? Or $\{1,2,3,4,6\}$?

Comment: I meant $\{\{1,4\}\}$. About ur two questions, i dont see how they can be in the intersection

Comment: There's no intersection in the problem. Do you claim that $\{1,3,4\}\subseteq\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ is not true? Or that $\{1,4\}\subseteq\{1,3,4\}$ is not true? or that $\{1,5\}\not\subseteq\{1,3,4\}$ is not true? If all of these _are_ true, then $\{1,3,4\}$ should, by definition, be in $A$.

Comment: @henning I cant understand you. Did I solve it or there are more elements in the intersection that I fail to see?

Comment: _Which_ intersection is it you speak about? There's still no intersection sign in the problem.